# How to hide Unique Characters?

Tags: disgaea-5

I noticed that the generic Nine-tails have higher stats (equipment aptitude?) compared to Izuna. In fact, I checked that each Overlord have lower stats when compared to their generic counterpart (Geese - Chimera, Drumdawn - Zwei Head, etc.) Even with balanced distributions, I find the generic versions more appealing.

Is there some sort of room or lobby that I can use to hide them? Like the Detention Hall in Disgaea 3 or the Supporter Room in Disgaea 4?

Comment: I don't know if this would really classify as an answer but you could use your three character groups and only add in your generic characters and leave out the unique characters you don't want.

Comment: Yes. I think your explanation would count as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no "Detention Hall"-like feature in Disgaea 5, as explained [here](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/835980-disgaea-5-alliance-of-vengeance/72629578). However, there are ways to make your unique characters disappear if you don't want to have to see them. From the above thread:

> You can send them out to other netherworlds if you don't want to see them

A particularly interesting and useful way to use these characters is this one:

> I recommend using dispatches, arranging your team so that the guys you don't care about will be the last ones down the list, and even having units for the sole purpose of delimiting your unit list (with names like "--USELESS--" or "--SUPPORT--").

Another suggestion with dispatches:

> You can also set up a dispatch squad of the people you use by hitting the square button in the character list screen and then you won't see all the characters